# ResourceManager.GetString() not returning value

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, global, resource-files

I am trying to implement multiple language support for my web project. I am new to it.

I am  not able to get the resource file value by using ResourceManager.GetString() function. I am passing the name and current CuluralInfo. The resource file present in my App_GlobalResources are Sample.resx, Sample.en-us.resx, Sample.zh-cn.resx and Sample.ar-sa.resx. I am having a name field named "Heading1" and its value in all the resource files

My code is like

```
  string Heading1= Resources.Global.ResourceManager.GetString(("Heading1", Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture);
```

But it is always returning null value. Please help me to get the solution for this problem

Thanks 
San

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the problem

The code should be like

```
string Heading1= Resources.Sample.ResourceManager.GetString(name, culture_object);
```